# Drawable Resource file fill width

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I'm creating a splash screen and I want the image in my drawable resource file to be centered, have a width of something like match_parent and a height of something like wrap_content. This seems like it's painfully easy to do in a layout file but is proving difficult for me in a drawable. I've tried playing around with gravity and bitmaps but still no luck. Any help is appreciated

Here is what I have

**splash_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white_logo_small"
        android:width="383dp"
        android:height="152dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</layer-list>
```

Basically I want to achieve this effect in a drawable file (just a centered, full width image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_logo_small" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is your image-drawable a picture file like PNG? If yes, use vector-drawables instead, especially for this case: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources. You cannot properly size your image-drawables in the `layer-list`, it will always be the size of your image-drawable.

Comment: Yes I was using a PNG. I converted it to a vector drawable but am still not sure how to get it to fill the width and wrap the content of the height

Comment: Please explain your expected behavior and your intention.

Comment: For any screen size, I want the vector asset to fill the width of the screen while maintaining the aspect ratio and also being centered

Comment: Did you tried to set a scale type in your ImageView? Such as: android:scaleType="fitCenter".. There are other values you could try such as centerCrop, centerInside, fitStart, fitEnd.. so, I think you could check that.. test both orientations (portrait/landscape).. You can set any of those: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: Yes that's the type of behavior I want, but I want it in a drawable bitmap or something similar to that. The image view was only an example of what I wanted